# strcpy to multi-dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I've been having issues attempting to copy a word into a multi-dimensional array.

Here is the code I use to create the array:

```cpp
char *word_buffer;
char *return_result[64];

int buffer_count = 0;
int word_start = 0;
int word_end = 0;

// Some extra, irreverent code.

for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    if (text[i] == delim) { // Delim is a value such as '\n'
        word_end = i;
        word_buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*64);
        strncpy(word_buffer, text + word_start, word_end - word_start); // Copy the word into word_buffer
        strcpy(*(return_result + buffer_count), word_buffer);

        word_start = i + 1;
    }
    
}
```

I believe my issue lies with the last line. I attempt to give `strcpy` a pointer to the address of the 2d array where I want the result of `word_buffer` to be place. However, this results in a Segmentation Fault.

The goal is to have an array of words returned. I.E.

```cpp
char *result[10] = { "foo", "bar", "x", "y", "z" };
```

But to have this done dynamically with code. My code to split the words is working fine. Though, I don't know how to place the value into a 2d array.

Edit: User SHR recommended I try replacing the `strcpy` line with `return_array[buffer_count]=word_buffer;`. This does partially work but it crashes after a random amount of values in the array every time. I don't really see how this could be due to high memory usage. Tracking the memory usage of the binary shows nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: What is the type of `return_array`? What is the type of `buffer_count`? Basically, as written, this code is nonsense. Too many missing pieces. Nobody can tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: assuming `return_result` is `return_array`. why not just do: `return_array[i]=word_buffer;`? otherwise there is memory leak.

Comment: OT: `sizeof(char)` is [guaranteed to be 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#1.sentence-4).

Comment: Are you sure this is C++? It looks very C-ish.

Comment: Yes, `return_result` and `return_array` are the same value. Sorry about that. I did try what you said but this seems to cause a Segmentation Fault after 1428 values (not sure if that value is significant or not). Changing the size of the array doesn't change anything either

Comment: @FredLarson: No it is not correct C either: there is a cast of the result of malloc, so it is probably compiled as C++...

Comment: @SergeBallesta: I didn't say it was *correct* C, I said it was *C-ish*. And while casting the result of `malloc()` is a [topic of some debate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10077), it is not invalid C.

Comment: @NathanBitTheMoon Do you mean it crashes after trying to store 1428 strings into `return_result`?  Of course it does; `return_result` only has space for 64 strings.  You should really just use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of all this raw array of `char*` stuff.